# Elementary OS - Hera 5.1 - Can't login - "Session returned error code 1" - Accidently removed zeitgeist*

Tags: linux, authentication, elementary-os, zeitgeist

I've accidently uninstalled zeitgeist by running `sudo apt-get purge zeitgeist*`

I can't login anymore. I've the following error message : "Session returned error code 1"

[Error message from io.elementary.greeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bsvi.jpg)

Observations :

- It tests the password (if I don't tip the right one, it tells me wrong password)
- I can login use the command line tty (by pressing Ctrl Alt F1).
- When I try to run `io.elementary.greeter`, I've the error message "Unable to init server: Impossible to connect: Connection refused" (and it tells me it can't use GTK on this display but nevermind)
- When I try the same command line with `sudo`, I've more errors : "dconf-warning **: 18:28:41.795: failed to commit changes to dconf: Impossible de lancer automatiquement D-bus sans $DISPLAY X11" (this last sentence meaning "Impossible to automaticly run D-bus without $DISPLAY X11")

If any of you know any solution instead of uninstalling the whole OS and reinstalling, I'll be realy thanksful.

Comment: Easiest solution is probably to check in the [apt or dpkg logs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425809/where-are-the-logs-for-apt-get) from the tty (`Ctrl+Alt+F1`) with tools like `cat`, `tail` or `less`. After you know which packages you accidentally purged, you can reinstall them with apt-get.

Answer (score 6):

[ RESOLVED ]

Following [this link](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21532/cannot-login-to-my-original-account-io-elementary-greeter-unable-to-log-in-star) that leads to [this other link](https://www.pc-prime.com/blog/unable-login-elementary-freya/), I've repaired it.

2 steps :

1 - I've removed the .Xauthority file in my home directory and then I've run `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade`

2 - I've run `sudo apt-get install pantheon-xsession-settings` and reboot (command `reboot`)

Now seems to work fine :-)

I hope it will help, GL HF ! ;-)

Comment: You saved me...!
 In my case I reinstalled wingpanel then restarted and got the same error.